# hadoop's poor scheduling of tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running some map reduce tasks on hadoop. The mapper is used to generate data and hence does not depend upon the hdfs block placement. To test my system I am using 2 nodes and one master node. I am doing my testing on hadoop-2.0 with yarn.

There is something very uncomfortable that I find with hadoop. I have configured it to run 8 maps tasks. Unfortunately hadoop is launching all the 8 map tasks on one node, and the other node is almost ideal. There are 4 reducers, and it does not balance these reducers too. It really results in a poor performance when that happens.

I have these properties set in mapred-site.xml in both the job tracker and task tracker

```
 <property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
    <value>2</value>
  </property>
```

Can some one explain if this problem can be solved or why does such problem exists with hadoop?

Comment: can you describe more about "generate data and hence does not depend upon the hdfs block placement." to understand source of data for job?

Comment: Its basically like random text generator in hadoop, where mappers generate random data. You don't really need input data source for that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of mappers/reducers as one to one with servers. What it sounds like is happening is your system knows that the load is so low their is no need to launch reducers across the cluster. It is trying to avoid the network overhead of transfering files from master to the slave nodes.

Think of the number of mappers and reducers as how many concurrent threads you will allow your cluster to run. This is important when determing how much memory to allocate for each mapper/reducer.

To force an even distrubtion you could try allocating enough memory for each mapper/reducer to make it require a whole node. For example, 4 nodes, 8 mappers. Force each mapper to have 50% of the ram on each node. Not sure if this will work as expected, but really Hadoop load balancing itself is something good in theory, but might not seem that way for small data situations.